# Stream tweets from Twitter (With Tweepy and Python) and store in SQLite database until N tweets has been processed

Tags: python, database, sqlite, twitter, tweepy

I a trying to store N tweets (filtered by the keyword "Trump") in a SQLite database table ("sentiment"). For this purpose, I have written a function "count_rows" that returns the integer number of rows stored in this table (each row corresponds to a tweet). Using this integer amount as a cutoff for reaching exactly N tweets I am attempting to stream tweets inside a while loop (see below):

```
N = 100

def count_rows():
    count_SQL = """SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sentiment"""
    c.execute(count_SQL)
    return c.fetchall()[0][0]

num_rows = count_rows()  # Starts at value: zero
while num_rows <= N:
    try:
        auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
        auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)
        twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
        twitterStream.filter(track=["Trump"])
        # num_rows = count_rows()
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
        time.sleep(5)
    num_rows = count_rows()
```

The challenge is, that the streaming goes on forever, and the while loop is infinite. What am I doing wrong? Am I using the count_rows() in a wrong way? (the function count_rows() itself works as it should, so the error must be within my while-loop logic I suppose).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[*Note to self: remember to read **all** the words in a post* :]

**EDIT:**

From the [tweepy doc:](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/streaming_how_to.html#async-streaming)

> Streams [do]  not terminate unless the connection is closed,

Shouldn't the count test be *inside* the listener? It sounds like the call to `Stream` is not going to return to the while function.

---

Does this `num_rows = count_rows()` continuously reset num_rows to 0? There is no indication in the posted code that the `COUNT(*)` in `sentiments` changes. Are the tweets being inserted into `sentiment` table?

Comment: inside my while-loop, the line: twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())   is calling the listener class (that inherits from the StreamListener class), which saves streamed tweets into the sentiments table. So every time a "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sentiments" query is performed, a higher number appears.

Comment: Thanks @DinoCoderSaurus, I moved the logic into the listener class, and now receive exactly the number of tweets I want. Awesome!